# how can i register a Flask-Admin BaseView as a module

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

How can I register a Flask-Admin BaseView as a module in my application? every time I run my app I get a blueprint collision  error!

I also know about ModelView in Flask-Admin, but I want to separate models and views from each other.

> init.py

```
from flask import Flask
import flask_admin as admin
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from views.user import user_view, UserView

admin = admin.Admin(app, name='Backend')
user_view.add_view(UserView)

db.create_all()
```

> Package Folder Backend

```
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── static
├── templates
│   └── user
│       └── index.html
└── views
    ├── __init__.py
    └── user.py
```

> models.py

```
from . import db


class UserModel(db.Model):
    '__tablename__' == "User"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    # Required for administrative interface. For python 3 please use __str__ instead.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

> user.py

```
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from Backend import app

user_view = Admin(app, name="User")


class UserView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('user/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I answer my own question. it was just a fallacy.

I just need to import the `UserView` as described [here](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1.0/quickstart/#adding-views). And also need to import the package app in the view.

So here is the relation between `__init__.py` and `views/user.py`.

> **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
import flask_admin as admin
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from views.user import UserView

admin = admin.Admin(app, name='Backend')
admin.add_view(UserView(name="User"))

db.create_all()
```

> views/user.py

```
from Backend import app
from flask_admin import BaseView, expose


class UserView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('user/index.html')
```

**This part [from Flask Documentaion:](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) was interessting.**

> ### Circular Imports:
>
> Every Python programmer hates them, and yet we just added some:
>   circular imports (That’s when two modules depend on each other. In
>   this case views.py depends on **init**.py). Be advised that this is a
>   bad idea in general but here it is actually fine. The reason for this
>   is that we are not actually using the views in **init**.py and just
>   ensuring the module is imported and we are doing that at the bottom of
>   the file.